# Setting Focus using catel:Focus on a custom control

Tags: catel

I've started catel:Focus behavior to set the focus on the first item of a view,this works fine on base controls but not on a custom one I've developed

Here's my code

Main control

```
 <views:PortfolioChooserControl x:Name="PortfolioChooserView" DataContext="{Binding PortfolioModel}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                               LoadDefaultValue="False" AllowNull="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0" Height="25" Focusable="True">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <catel:Focus FocusDelay="400"/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </views:PortfolioChooserControl>
```

and here's the custom usercontrol

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="xxx.Client.WPF.Controls.Portfolio.Views.PortfolioChooserControl"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
               xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:behaviors1="clr-namespace:xxx.Client.WPF.Core.Behaviors;assembly=IF.Tesoreria.Client.WPF.Core"
               xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
               xmlns:porfolio="clr-namespace:xxx.Client.WPF.Core.DraggingItems.Porfolio;assembly=IF.Tesoreria.Client.WPF.Core"
               CloseViewModelOnUnloaded="False">

<catel:UserControl.Resources>
    <behaviors1:PortfolioFilteringBehavior x:Key="PortfolioFilteringBehavior"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PortfolioSearchTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ap_Desc}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</catel:UserControl.Resources>

<AdornerDecorator>
    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox   
        x:Name="PortfolioCompleteBox" 
        TextSearchMode="Contains"
        AutoCompleteMode="Suggest"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        DisplayMemberPath="Ap_Desc"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        SearchText="{Binding SearchTextPortfolio, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PortfolioList}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        FilteringBehavior="{StaticResource PortfolioFilteringBehavior}" 
        DropDownItemTemplate="{StaticResource PortfolioSearchTemplate}"
        AllowDrop="True">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <porfolio:PortfolioDropperBehavior></porfolio:PortfolioDropperBehavior>
            <!--<catel:Focus FocusDelay="400" />-->
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

If I put the behavior in the custom control (you see it commented) it works but this cause problem when I've 2 portfolio inside the view because it focuses on the last...

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your PortfolioChooserControl probably has a container grid that is also able to retrieve the focus. Make sure to disable retrieving the focus on each container that shouldn't get any focus.

Comment: I've pasted all the code of my PortfolioChooserControl  but there's no grid or so on, I've also tried commenting out the adorner...